# Dual of a Reversible Markov Chain

Tags: pr.probability, markov-chains

Let a reversible Markov process $m_{t+1}=m_t P$, where $t$ is time that has a stationary distribution $\pi$. I saw in a paper that the dual system was defined as $x_{t+1}=P x_t$. Can anyone give me some directions in order to understand how this is derived?

Comment: That looks like the _definition_ of "dual system".  Derived from what?

Answer (score 6):

Let $y_t = x_t^T$. Then, $y_{t+1} = y_t P^T$. Thus, $y$ (and therefore $x$) corresponds to the original Markov Chain run backward in time.
Hope this gives some motivation towards the concept of dual chains.